# Add "block prefix" to all lines belonging to the same block of a file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I tried to make the title as specific as possible, an example should clear the problem.

I have a tab-separated file with lines starting with `1` to `5`. That is considered as a block (each block can have multiple entries of `4` and `5`).

- The next `1` defines the start of the next block and so on.
- My prefix is always in the line starting with `3`. I want to write that word at the begging of each line per block.

Any idea on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated. It doesn't have to be `sed`, it can be `awk`, but `sed` would be preferred.

- Example of input file

  ```
  1 foo1
  2 foo1
  3 bar1 | Prefix block 1
  4 foo1
  5 foo1
  1 foo2
  2 foo2
  3 bar2 | Prefix block 2
  4 foo2
  4 foo3
  5 foo2
  5 foo3
  ```
- Desired output for this input example

  ```
  bar1 1 foo1
  bar1 2 foo1
  bar1 3 bar1
  bar1 4 foo1
  bar1 5 foo1
  bar2 1 foo2
  bar2 2 foo2
  bar2 3 bar2
  bar2 4 foo2
  bar2 4 foo3
  bar2 5 foo2
  bar2 5 foo3
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, a two-pass `awk` solution comes to mind (which means we have to specify the input filename *twice* as operands on the command-line). It assumes the tokens on the line are separated by `\t` on input, and are to be separated by `\t` on output, too.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
     NR==FNR{if ($1=="3") pre[++i]=$2;next} $1=="1" {j++} {print pre[j],$0}' input input
```

In the first pass, where `NR` (the global line counter) is equal to `FNR` (the per-file line-counter), we fill an array `pre` with prefixes every time we encounter a line with first field (`$1`) equal to `3`. So, `pre` is a mapping between "block number" and associated prefix. Apart from that, we print nothing and immediately skip execution to the next line.

In the second pass, we increase a block counter `j` every time we find the "start block" condition (first field `$1` equal to `1`), and for all lines prepend the prefix corresponding to the block counter.

Comment: Thank you for helping and for the explanation. It works for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

**GNU sed** running in extended regex mode `-E` plus autoprint off `-n` so that
We know when to print.

```
sed -En '
  #--------------------------------
  # printing the block in pattern space
  #--------------------------------
  /\n/{
    s/.*\n(.*)/\1&/
    P;/\n.*\n/D;$d;g
  }

  #--------------------------------
  # collect block
  #--------------------------------

  :15
  /^1/{
    N;h
    /\n5/!b15

    #--------------------------------
    # collect trailing 5 lines
    #--------------------------------
    :tail5
      $bend
      n
    /^5/{H;$!btail5;}

    #--------------------------------
    # place block prefix @ eol
    #--------------------------------
    $!x;$g
    :end
    s/.*\n3\t([^\n]+)\n.*/\n&\n\1\t/
    D; # take me to block print section
  }
' file
```

**Result:**

```
bar1    1   foo1
bar1    2   foo1
bar1    3   bar1
bar1    4   foo1
bar1    5   foo1
bar2    1   foo2
bar2    2   foo2
bar2    3   bar2
bar2    4   foo2
bar2    4   foo3
bar2    5   foo2
bar2    5   foo3
```